# AMChart PieChart DrillDown With Multiple Data Source

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts, drilldown

This code create a AM piechart, now I want to know how to create drill-down. For example, if I clicked the specific of a slice it will show new data, this data will be an external source(json file). Then there will be a back button to go back to the main chart, then if clicked other slice in pie chart new chart will show up depends on the data source(json file).

I already searched for other drill-down in AM PieChart but what I dont find what exactly I'm looking for.

```
var chart1 = AmCharts.makeChart("chartPieMostSolddiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "dataPieJson.json",
    "complete": function(chart1){
        if (chart1.legend === undefined || chart1.legend.truncateLabels === undefined)
            return;

          // init fields
          var titleField = chart1.titleField;
          var legendTitleField = chart1.titleField+"Legend";

          // iterate through the data and create truncated label properties
          for(var i = 0; i < chart1.dataProvider.length; i++) {
            var label = chart1.dataProvider[i][chart1.titleField];
            if (label.length > chart1.legend.truncateLabels)
              label = label.substr(0, chart1.legend.truncateLabels-1)+'...'
              chart1.dataProvider[i][legendTitleField] = label;
          }

          // replace chart.titleField to show our own truncated field
          chart1.titleField = legendTitleField;

          // make the balloonText use full title instead
          chart1.balloonText = chart1.balloonText.replace(/\[\[title\]\]/, "[["+titleField+"]]");
                },
                "showCurtain": false
              },
              "titleField": "prod_name",
              "valueField": "quantity",
              "autoWrap": true,
              "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
              "innerRadius": "30%"

});
```

[My Piechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQZSf.jpg)

Hope someone can provide me an answer. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/drill-down-pie-chart/

Comment: yes, but its data is in var chartData; 
what I want is to get the data for pieChart from my different json file. 
Is it possible?